# Validaing Date Range

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
Date1:23/05/2013  Date 2:29/05/2013
```

Now I have 2 dateTimePickers(namely dtDateStart  and dtDateFinish  respectively) and a submit button.

I want to validate on Submit button click, so it should not accept the dates between these 2 Dates(given above);

```
if (dtDateStart >= Date1 && dtDateFinish <= Date2)
                    {
                        //some operation
                    }
```

This code is working if we select the dates with in the range.
This code is not working when we select the dates like 20/05/2013 and 25/05/2013 and also with the dates 28/05/2013 and 01/06/2013.
Do you have any idea on how to write the if condition?

Comment: CAn u Simulate the same on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: You have to rearrange your date, to start with year/month/day

Answer (score 1):

Date comparison is not done like that.

```
function compareDates(d1, d2) {
    var ms = d1 - d2;  // difference in miliseconds
    return ms > 0 ? true : false;    
};
```

If you need to compare different time units, you need to convert. The below is for checking by days(your dates must be at least 1 day apart).

```
 function compareDates(d1, d2) {
        var ms = d1 - d2,  // difference in miliseconds
            hours = ms / 3600,
            days = hours / 24,
            weeks = days / 7;
        return days > 0 ? true : false;    
 };
```

Tweak to your needs.

```
if (compareDates(dtDateStart, Date1) && compareDates(Date2, dtDateFinish)) {
    // dates are within range.
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your dates to milliseconds, it will make it easier to compare:

```
var date1 = new Date("05/23/2013").getTime(), // 1369263600000
    date2 = new Date("05/29/2013").getTime(), // 1369782000000
    myDate = new Date("05/25/2013").getTime(); // 1369436400000

if (myDate >= date1 && myDate <= date2) {
    console.log(true);
}
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/iqeros/1/edit)